# Error: Support for the experimental syntax 'optionalChaining' isn't currently enabled, but it is

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, babeljs, nuxt.js

I've followed the instructions [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining) and [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator) and I've added the following to my `package.json`

```
},
"babel": {
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"
    ]
},
"dependencies": {
```

But I'm still getting the error

```
Support for the experimental syntax 'optionalChaining' isn't currently enabled
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe silly question but did you install the packages npm insall/ yarn add?

Comment: I have, yes lol

Comment: Are you using webpack? If so could you add the webpack.config.js?

Comment: Adding those plugins to my webpack config worked for me in removing that error message. I think instead of adding those plugins to the `package.json`, try adding it to your webpack config -- under the `options` key for the `babel-loader` rule/entry. Another possibility is adding it to your `.babelrc` file (if you have one in your project).

Comment: Not a direct solution since I can't know what your setup is, but: Search for any `@babel/plugin-proposal-` across the codebase. It may live in multiple files, sometimes twice in the same file. This has worked for me.

Comment: Are you using node > 12, cause we used to have an issue with optional chaining on node 14 in a nuxt project, the issue was gone after we go back to node 12.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I am bit late here, but I can see the question is still active, for those come later:

At the time of writing, optional chaining **might** not work in NUXT project with node > 12, try using the current LTS version (node 12).

I think the issue might related to one or more dependencies of NUXT but we didn't investigate further, using node 12 resolves the issue for us.

Comment: Thanks for replying, this might help someone. I personally haven't experienced this issue as of late projects. `create-react-app` and `create-next-app` support most proposals and ES features OOTB now.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem，
I was using Vue CLI ，the reason is that the scaffolding version is too low (plugins installed separately seem to be ignored), you can check and upgrade your project  scaffolding

Comment: How do you do this sorry?